# ¿Qué significan "achichuca" y "achichay" en Colombia?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, colombia

Recientemente escuché estas dos palabras del español de Colombia y quisiera saber qué significan. Agradecería si también me pueden decir el origen de estas palabras, que no parecen provenir del español directamente.

Comment: Por "achichay" no viene nada, pero [achachay](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=achachay) sí está en el dicccionario de la RAE: "interjección para denotar aplauso o aprobación".

Comment: Ambas parecen palabras de alguna lengua originaria (aka indígena) de Colombia. Es por eso que no parecen palabras españolas o derivadas del latín.

Comment: Es bueno aclarar que la influencia Quechua en Colombia está muy limitada a una pequeña zona del suroccidente, limítrofe con Ecuador y Perú (ver mapa en la respuesta de @Harvey SIERRA COLEY). Estos términos no se usan ni se entienden en la mayor parte del país.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buscando por internet en inglés, he encontrado [esta página](http://raisingcolombiankids.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/language-of-pasto-achichuca-achichai.html) en inglés sobre el idioma de los jóvenes colombianos de Pasto, de la cual traduzco el párrafo relevante:

> Dos palabras que resultarán familiares y únicas de esta área [Pasto]: Achichuca y Achichai. Son interjecciones que como nos enseñó la "School House Rock" [?] expresan nerviosismo y emoción.
>
> ACHICHUCA se usa cuando te quemas o cuando algo está muy caliente. Por ejemplo: "ACHICHUCA, me quemé el dedo".
>
> ACHICHAI se usa cuando algo está muy frío. Por ejemplo, es una mañana gélida en Pasto, y podrías oír a alguien decir: "¡ACHICHAI!"

Vale la pena comentar que "achichai" sí está en el [diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/achachay), pero con un significado algo diferente:

> "interjección para denotar aplauso o aprobación".

Sí viene la acepción de frío, pero para Ecuador, no Colombia. Y para complicarlo más, en Perú, siempre según la RAE, indica **miedo**.

"Achichuca" no viene en el diccionario.

Respecto al origen, la RAE menciona que "achichai" proviene del quechua. Supongo que la otra también es de ese mismo origen.

Answer (score 5):

Como comentaron anteriormente, *achichuca* significa `qué calor` y *achichai* `qué frío`.

Estas dos palabras provienen de la lengua quechua originaria de Perú y diseminada por toda la región andina de Suramérica, específicamente por lo que en la actualidad se conoce como norte de Argentina, Bolivia, Chile, suroeste colombiano (Pasto), Ecuador y Perú.

[image]

Tomado de https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_quechuas

Answer (score 2):

Hola estas palabras son muy típicas de mi ciudad Pasto en Colombia, nuestro país tiene diversos regionalismos con diferentes palabras dependiendo del departamento o región del país a la que visites Pasto capital de Nariño es rica en este tipo de palabras Achichai es utilizada como una expresión por ejemplo si hace mucho frío exclamas !Achichai! Y así mismo sucede con achicuca en caso de mucho calor.

Answer (score 1):

Achichuca es mucho calor y Achichai mucho frio

Comment: Hola Sandra y bienvenida a [spanish.se]. Así como está, ahora mismo la respuesta es apenas un comentario. Échale una ojeada a [answer] para ver cómo mejorarla.

Answer (score 1):

Achichay en Nariño, el lenguaje ya extinto, es una expresión para decir "Ay qué frío".

Y Achichucas es lo contrario, es la expresión para decir "Ay qué calor".

Solo lo dicen en el sur-occidente de Colombia, Nariño.

Además es muy difícil encontrar información de dicho lenguaje indígena extinto de los Pastos...

Answer (score -1):

achuchucas se me hizo una ampoya en el dedo,eso te pasa por ser tan bambaro,anda y te colocas un hielo  en ese dedo por 5 minutos.
chichai ese hielo pues eso te toca aguantar guagua si hubieras metido esas manotas al la parrilla de la estufa no te hubieras quemado eso te pasa por andar mamando gallo.fue la forma en que me castigo mi madre,yo vivo y naci en pasto,nariño,colombia

Comment: gracias por la respuesta Nótese que esto ya lo indicaron respuestas anteriores –

Answer (score -1):

se lo hubiera metido en el locu mejor y gritado q viva pasto carajo ...  seguro los españoles vieron q no habia nada mas q pasto y hierba y por eso le nombraron pasto a la ciudad mientras fornicaban  a las pobres indigenas de la zona sur de nuestro territorio yo le hubiera nombrado "Achuchu"